# Show git impact per user

Tags: git, version-control, dvcs

Is there a way to take an existing git repository and display the number of lines committed per person?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should investigate [GitStats](http://gitstats.sourceforge.net/).
Here is a [sample](http://gitstats.sourceforge.net/examples/git/authors.html) of what you may be looking for.